# ¿Se puede utilizar la Función "AVG" con WHERE IN en SQL?

Tags: sql

**Requerimiento:**

Necesito obtener el promedio (average) de Reviews de varios usuarios con una única consulta.

**¿Qué fue lo que intenté?:**

```
SELECT AVG(rating) AS rating FROM reviews WHERE id IN ($idsList)
```

**El problema:**

La consulta sql devuelve un único resultado. Esto significa que se están tomando todas las reviews de todos los usuarios y se están promediando entre sí.

**¿Qué debería pasar?:**

Se debería calcular el promedio de reviews correspondiente a cada ID. Esto significa que si $idsList tiene un tamaño de 10, entonces AVG deberá calcular el promedio de reviews para cada uno de esos 10 usuarios. ¿Cómo puedo lograrlo?

Comment: pero eso no es lo que está preguntando el op (aunque pudiera parecerlo según el título de la pregunta)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes casi todo listo, sólo te falta usar un `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT 
    id,
    AVG(rating) AS rating 
FROM reviews 
WHERE id IN ($idsList)
GROUP BY id
;
```

Comment: Solucionado con GROUP BY. Muchisimas gracias por tu ayuda @Lamak , muy amable